# Oracle 10g installer disappears

Tags: oracle

I have been trying to install oracle 10g following this tutorial http://faq.programmerworld.net/database/installing-oracle-10g.html
however, the installer just disappears after choosing the installation path and hitting next.

Welcome page

[image: Welcome page]

Deinstall Products

[image: Deinstall Products]

Select Installation Type -> Enterprise Edition

[image: Select Installation Type -> Enterprise Edition]

Specify home details

[image: Specify home details: Name -> OraDb10g_home1 Path -> c:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1]

Product-Specific Prerequisite Checks

[image: Product-Specific Prerequisite Checks (all good)]

After the last step, the window just disappears, and nothing happens
I looked on the internet and tried various things, the last thing I've been trying to do is this solution http://www.dbforums.com/showthread.php?1641469-Oracle-Installer-Disappears   but I couldn't figure out how to do what is said.

Comment: I had a similar issue some day. Turned out that we received an incomplete installer disk and the install process was just sitting in the background. The collegue who handed out the disk just copied ~700 MB of the folder but it should've been ~1.3 GB (he made a CD instead of a DVD).

Comment: Hmm, good point, I must verify that, cause I copied it from another pc too, thanks for the enlightenment!!

Comment: We used FileMon (from Sysinternals) to monitor the process, and it was just sitting there, idling, after having copied a bunch of files. So we concluded it was out of input. The installer wasn't obviously programmed to check its manifest for completeness.

Comment: Why do you like to install a 15 years old software which is out of support for many years.

Comment: Cause we're forced to use it

Comment: What **version** and **edition** of Windows is this?

Answer (score 0):

Read this troubleshooting installation guide: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/install.102/b14317/ts.htm#NTDBX404

The first thing I would do is go see if you can find the installation logs, see if you can at least find an error code.

Comment: Thank you, I'll go through it and try to do what you told me